# Children's transport-themed game book, possibly European

Tags: identify-this-game

From the 1970's - a large-format hardback children's book where each double-page spread was a transport-themed game with cut-out cardboard pieces.

Most of the games were more complex than basic roll-and-move - some were more like puzzles (e.g. move so many railway carriages into a siding with limited space) whereas others involved moving pedestrian pieces around road systems.

I am sure it was a (translated) European book because a) the designs of the trains/trams etc. were unfamiliar (I'm in the UK) and b) the relatively complex nature of the games were in keeping with the Euro ethic.